# What is the difference between these two C functions in terms of handling memory?

Tags: c, linux, memory, cpu-architecture

```
typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;
void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, size_t len) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf(" %.2x", start[i]);    //line:data:show_bytes_printf
    printf("\n");
}

void show_integer(int* p,size_t len){
    size_t i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
       printf(" %d",p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Suppose I have two functions above, and I use main function to test my functions:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[5]={12345,123,23,45,1};
    show_bytes((byte_pointer)a,sizeof(a));
    show_integer(a,5);
}
```

I got the following results in my terminal:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/OS_project$ ./show_bytes
39 30 00 00 7b 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
12345 123 23 45 1
```

Can someone tell me why I got the result? I understand the second function, but I have no idea why I got `39 30 00 00 7b 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00 01 00 00 00` for the first function. Actually I know the number sequence above are hexadecimal decimal for `12345`, `123`, `23`, `45`, `1`. However, I have no idea: `start[i]` pointer doesn't point to the whole number such as `12345` or `123` in the first function. Instead, the `start[0]` just point to the least significant digit for the first number `12345`? Can someone help me explain why these two functions are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`12345` is `0x3039` in hex. because int is 32bits on your machine it will be represented as `0x00003039`. then because your machine is little endian it will be represented as `0x39300000`. you can read more about Big and Little endian on: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html

the same applies for other results.

Comment: but why that byte_pointer only points to some digits of 0x00003039 such as 00 or 39, why it didn't point to the whole number 0x00003039? in the second function p[i] refers to the whole number 12345, but in the first function, start[i] only refers to 00 or 39 instead of the whole number 0x00003039(12345)

Comment: because you read it byte by byte in first one, and read whole int in second one, an int is 4 byte(on your machine)

Answer (score 2):

On your platform, `sizeof(int)` is `4` and your platform uses little endian system. The binary representation of `12345` using a 32-bit representation is:

```
00000000 00000000 00110000 00111001
```

In a little endian system, that is captured using the following byte sequence.

```
00111001 00110000 00000000 00000000
```

In hex, those bytes are:

```
39 30 00 00
```

That's what you are seeing as the output corresponding to the first number.

You can do similar processing of the other numbers in the array to understand the output corresponding to them.